# When will GA4 Data API be moved to beta?

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-data-api

We are going to create an integration with the GA4 Data API, and are waiting for it to be moved to beta status. Are there any news about when this will happen?

Answer (score 1):

The Google analytics Data api is in beta now.

[image]

You can follow the [Change log](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/changelog)